# Dockerized tomcat is not starting

Tags: java, tomcat, ubuntu

I am new to docker and I have tried following some tutorials and documentation on USING DOCKER TO EFFICIENTLY CREATE MULTIPLE TOMCAT INSTANCES, but am having trouble getting the service to run via the docker run command.

I have a docker file with the following coding below

```
FROM ubuntu:precise
MAINTAINER Quinten Krijger < qkrijger [at] gmail {dot} com>

RUN echo "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main universe" > /etc/apt/sources.list

RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install python-software-properties

RUN add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java

RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y upgrade

RUN echo oracle-java7-installer shared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-1 select true | /usr/bin/debconf-set-selections

RUN apt-get -y install oracle-java7-installer && apt-get clean

RUN update-alternatives --display java

RUN echo "JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle" >> /etc/environment
```

When I build using the command

```
docker build -t quintenk/jdk7-oracle .
```

it shows the build is successful.

In the another dockerfile, I try to create create other images based on it

I have another docker in a different path with the following commands

```
FROM quintenk/jdk7-oracle

MAINTAINER Quinten Krijger "qkrijger@gmail.com"

RUN apt-get -y install tomcat7

RUN echo "JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle" >> /etc/default/tomcat7

EXPOSE 8080

CMD service tomcat7 start && tail -f /var/lib/tomcat7/logs/catalina.out
```

I use the following command to run the docker file

```
docker run -d quintenk/tomcat7
```

But it shows as tomcat instance fail

```
* Starting Tomcat servlet engine tomcat7

...fail!
```

If I give the command

```
docker ps
```

also there is no instance running on my machine

I'm obviously doing something wrong and I'm getting the behaviour on my OSX

Answer (score 0):

For testing you can create a Dockerfile with `CMD ["bash"].`
start the container then login to the container using the command

```
docker -it exec container_name bash
```

then start tomcat and checkout out the tomcat logs

Comment: I have created a new dockerfile with CMD ["bash"] and executed the command but when i execute it shows as                                              docker -it exec high_wozniak bash
flag provided but not defined: -it
See 'docker --help'.

Comment: `docker exec -it container_name  bash` try this

Comment: Yes the command worked , i have a folder with name bash and have a dockerfile inside the folder bash and it has the code CMD ["bash"].                           The result of the command is $ docker exec -it high_wozniak bash
root@ece227541990:/#

Comment: after seeing the prompt root@ece227541990:/#
Now you can run linux command and debug tomcat
`Run the following command 
root@ece227541990:/# service service tomcat7 start`

Comment: @codingLeef when I start the  command root@f321e9dc51ea:/# service tomcat7 start
 * Starting Tomcat servlet engine tomcat7       it says failed

Answer (score 0):

Try running the image with following command

```
docker run -dt --cap-add SYS_PTRACE quintenk/tomcat7
```

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this issue. Finally, I am able to run the tomcat.Follow below steps.

Step-1: open terminal **Ctrl+Alt+t**

Step-2: then on terminal go inside the running container, type commands

```
     sudo docker exec -it containerID /bin/bash
```

Now to check tomcat is running or not, type your container IP address followed by colon(:) 8080 port on the browser. like 172.17.0.2:8080.

Hope it helps!!